# How to get total users average time passed 7 days

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I want to get the per day total users average usage time for passed 7 days i written the the SQL for each users average time it's coming perfectly but i have an u\issues in LARAVEL SQL function please help fix this SQL.

```
$currentTime = Carbon::today();

    $userUsage = DB::table('active_user')
                ->select(DB::raw('acu_name as name'),
                    DB::raw('u_fname as fname'),
                    DB::raw('AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,acu_at,acu_et)) as averageTime'),
                    DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
                ->join('u_info_one', 'active_user.acu_name', '=', 'u_info_one.u_email')
                ->whereDate('acu_at', '<=', $currentTime)
                ->groupBy('acu_name')
                ->get();
```

[image]

Comment: Please use only related tag in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` for this, e.g.:

```
$userUsage = DB::table('active_user')
                ->select(DB::raw('acu_name as name'),
                    DB::raw('u_fname as fname'),
                    DB::raw('AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,acu_at,acu_et)) as averageTime'),
                    DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
                ->join('u_info_one', 'active_user.acu_name', '=', 'u_info_one.u_email')
                ->whereDate('acu_at', '<=', $currentTime)
                ->groupBy('acu_name', DB::raw('DATE(acu_at)'))
                ->get();
```

**update**

If you just need daily average for all the users, you can remove `acu_name` from group by, e.g.:

```
$userUsage = DB::table('active_user')
                ->select(DB::raw('acu_name as name'),
                    DB::raw('u_fname as fname'),
                    DB::raw('AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,acu_at,acu_et)) as averageTime'),
                    DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
                ->join('u_info_one', 'active_user.acu_name', '=', 'u_info_one.u_email')
                ->whereDate('acu_at', '<=', $currentTime)
                ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(acu_at)'))
                ->get();
```

Comment: this is for each users average or total users average?

Comment: I want the result like : totaverage = (acu_at - acu_et)/total users

Comment: Yes, it will give you average per each `acu_name` per day.

Comment: i need per day total user average usage

Comment: I attached the result

Comment: <?php
foreach($userUsage as $usUa)
     {
         $aveTime = (($usUa->number)/($usUa->averageTime));
          echo "['".$usUa->date."',".$aveTime."],";
    }
?>

this method is correct or not per day total time divide by total users

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer is

```
    $userUsage = DB::table('active_user')
                ->select(DB::raw('DATE(acu_at) as date'),
                    DB::raw('AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,acu_at,acu_et)) as averageTime'),
                    DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT `acu_name`) as users'))
                ->join('u_info_one', 'active_user.acu_name', '=', 'u_info_one.u_email')
                ->whereDate('acu_at', '<=', $currentTime)
                ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(acu_at)'))
                ->orderBy(DB::raw('DATE(acu_at)'))
                ->get();

foreach($userUsage as $usUa)
   {
     $avegTime = ($usUa->averageTime/$usUa->users);
     echo "['".$usUa->date."',".$avegTime."],";
   }
```